# Query to get the rows in a table where value in column 1 is mapped to exactly one value in column 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `T1` like below:

```
COL1  COL2                   
---------------
aaa   10 
bbb   20                     
bbb   20                     
bbb   10                     
ccc   30                     
ccc   30                     
aaa   30                     
ddd   30
```

I want `col1` and `col2` values where `col1` is mapped to only one `col2`.

```
COL1 COL2                   
-----------
ccc 30                     
ddd 30
```

Please let me know how to achieve my goal.

I tried with the following to get required result set:

```
select distinct col1, col2 
 from t1 
where col1 in (select col1 
                 from (select distinct col1, col2 from t1) 
                group by col1 
               having count(col2) = 1);
```

What are the other options without having those many inner queries.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  Col1
,       max(Col2) as Col2
from    YourTable
group by
        Col1
having  count(distinct Col2) = 1
```

The `having` clause makes sure there's only one `Col2` in a single group.  You can display it using `max`, `min` or even `avg`.

See it [working at SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82e72/2/0) (thanks to Amit Singh.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Distinct A.Col1,A.Col2 from Table1 A
inner join 
(Select Col1,Count(Distinct Col2) as col3 from Table1 group by Col1) B on
A.Col1=B.Col1 and B.Col3=1
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ad5a/5)